# python scipy using fmin_bfgs for logistic regression

Tags: python, scipy, regression, logistics

I use the formula below as my hypothesis:
[image: hypothesis]

And the formula below as the cost function:
[image: cost function for one sample]

So the object function I try to minimize is :
[image: object function]

And the gradient is:
[image: gradient]

the csv file is formatted like:
y0,x1,x2,x3,...
y1,x1,x2,x3,...
y2,x1,x2,x3,...
y is either 1 or 0(for classification)
the training code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs
import pylab as pl



data = np.genfromtxt('../data/small_train.txt', delimiter=',')
y = data[:,0]
#add 1 as the first column of x, the constant term
x = np.append(np.ones((len(y), 1)), data[:,1:], axis = 1)

#sigmoid hypothesis
def h(theta, x):
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-np.dot(theta, x)))

#cost function
def cost(theta, x, y):
    tot = 0
    for i in range(len(y)):
        tot += y[i]*np.log(h(theta, x[i])) + (1-y[i])*(1-np.log(h(theta, x[i])))
    return -tot / len(y)

#gradient

def deviation(theta, x, y):
    def f(theta, x, y, j):
        tot = 0.0
        for i in range(len(y)):
            tot += (h(theta, x[i]) - y[i]) * x[i][j]
        return tot / len(y)
    ret = []
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        ret.append(f(theta, x, y, j))
    return np.array(ret)
    

init_theta = np.zeros(len(x[0]))
ret = fmin_bfgs(cost, init_theta, fprime = deviation, args=(x,y))
print ret
```

I run the code on a small data set, but it seems my implementation is not right.Can any one help me?
One more question:As you know, fmin_bfgs do not necessarily need the fprime term, what is the difference between if we do provide it and do not?

Comment: Providing the derivatives of the function only helps with speed as far as I know. If you don't provide an analytical form then numerical ones are generated on the fly. scikits.learn has a logistical regression function, you can try that one out to for testing.

Comment: @lhdgriver How did u get started and implemented the above code as m doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to correct something in the above code.

I think that the cost function should as follows (the correction is in bold):

```
#cost function
def cost(theta, x, y):
    tot = 0
    for i in range(len(y)):
        tot += y[i]*np.log(h(theta, x[i])) + (1-y[i])*(**np.log(1-h(theta, x[i]**)))
    return -tot / len(y)
```

Please let me know if it is better like this, thank you very much!